# Why OpenCV does not apply antialiasing when drawing on grayscale image?

Tags: opencv

Here's the code I use to create new image, draw a circle onto it and show it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# create 50x50 image, filled with white
img = np.ones((50,50))
# draw a circle onto the image
cv2.circle(img, (25,25), 10, 0, 2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
# show the image on the screen
cv2.imshow("i", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, no antialiasing seems to be applied (I upscaled the image x10):
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the image depth is not `CV_8U`, the `line_type` is automatically set to `8`.

From [`opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp#L1879):

```
if( line_type == CV_AA && img.depth() != CV_8U )
    line_type = 8;
```

Since the type of `numpy.ones` defaults to `numpy.float64`, you're losing the antialiased line.

Comment: As I understand, you need to create an image like this:
`np.zeros((50, 50), dtype=np.uint8)`